# AutoHotkey loop script

Tags: autohotkey

I need help creating an autohotkey loop script that does the following: presses the number 2 and holds left click for 5 seconds then releases. I want the script to repeat that function 3 times then after the third time it holds down x for 15 seconds, then repeats the entire process from the beginning again. This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
mbutton::

loop, 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

{
Send 2 {Click down}
Sleep 5
Send 2 {Click down}
Sleep 5
Send 2 {Click down}
Sleep 5
Send (x down)
Sleep 15
}

]::
pause

\::reload
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates the input you specified:

```
loop {
  loop 3 {
    send 2
    click down
    sleep 5000
    click up
  }
  send {x down}
  sleep 15000
  send {x up}
}
```

You really didn't describe exactly how your code isn't working.  Consider pruning statements that are working so we only need to look at the problem code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)